# Karate Cannot Assert XML Response Contains XPath

Tags: karate

I am trying to assert if an xml contains an xpath. For example the xpath is: `//vmap:AdBreak[@timeOffset='00:00:20']`

When I check it on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html it successfully returns an element.

However when I tried using below karate mechanism, it fails:

```
    Given url "https://ray.mond.com/"
    And header Content-Type = 'application/xml'
    And path "vmap/vmap.xml"
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * print response
    * xml resp = response
    * def vmap = //vmap:AdBreak[@timeOffset='00:00:20']
    * match resp contains vmap
```

The error is

```
xpath does not exist: //vmap:AdBreak[@timeOffset='00:00:20'] on response
```

Am I doing it the wrong way? I am trying to follow the docs here https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature .

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, XPath has some weird behavior at times. I'd appreciate if you can help troubleshoot and fix. This is not a priority for us as JSON is the most common case.

But here is your workaround:

```
* def vmap = /VMAP/AdBreak[@timeOffset='00:00:20']
```

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks. Will do try to check on it later.

However, I tried your suggestion but the test still fails as it complains:

`reason: all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys: [vmap:AdBreak]`

Comment: @Raymond sorry, `contains` is not that straightforward in XML. please ask a new question with a simple, specific example. also your test seems to be a very strange one, you have an XML, select a part out of it and then try to do a `contains`, you should be creating an expected XML and comparing it instead. and there is typically no need to use `xml` instead of `def`

Comment: Ah sorry @Peter, misunderstood your solution. 

It works perfectly when I do

`* match response /VMAP/AdBreak[@timeOffset='00:00:20'] == '#notnull'`

Thanks as always